# Import data into SiteFinity

Tags: database, sitefinity

Very new to SiteFinity. How does one taking an existing DB, say in CSV or excel format, and import items into siteFinity to interact with on SF pages?
I would like to do one data set as Products, and perhaps another just as a custom content type. But how to I import the already existing data? Should I use .Net or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a ServiceStack service (comes with sitefinity) to expose that csv data then just consume it wherever as Json... if the intent is to keep updating the CSV as the primary data source?  I'm not sure of the usecase here, do you have an external system that dumps to this file or something?

What you *should* do if that's not the case is to use the ModuleBuilder (/Sitefinity/Administration/Module-builder)  to create your data type in Sitefinity, then run a script to import the data (you make it, the MB gives you sample import code based on your structure).

Now you have better data entry, and it's all exposed properly though an API\OData endpoint to use (not to mention all widgets are autogenerated).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create dynamic module include data field of your item. Then you can use .net to create api or sthing to import CSV.

Example code for you with Product data with No and Title Field.

```
//read data from CSV
var attachedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["CsvDoc"];
if (attachedFile == null || attachedFile.ContentLength <= 0) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No data");
var csvReader = new StreamReader(attachedFile.InputStream);
string inputDataRead;
var values = new List<string>();
while ((inputDataRead = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //values.Add(inputDataRead.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", " "));
    values.Add(inputDataRead);
}
values.Remove(values[0]);

//import to CMS                
var dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
var contentType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Product.Product");

foreach (var value in values)
{
      var eachValue = value.Split(',');
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eachValue[0]))
      {
           using (new ElevatedModeRegion(dynamicModuleManager))
           {
                 var newcontent = dynamicModuleManager.CreateDataItem(contentType);
                 newcontent.SetValue("No", eachValue[0] != "" ? eachValue[0] : string.Empty);
                 newcontent.SetValue("Title", eachValue[1] != "" ? eachValue[1] : string.Empty);
                 newcontent.UrlName = Regex.Replace(eachValue[1].ToLower(), @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-");;
                 newcontent.Author = "ImportCSV";
                 newcontent.SetWorkflowStatus(dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published");
                 dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();                                
            }
      }
}
```

CSV File like this:

No,Title

1,Product1

2,Product2